# Loop over Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function showJobCategoryContent($id){

     $jobsInfoById = DB::table('jobs')->where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);

     // Imagine here i got 5 data

     foreach ($jobsInfoById as $jobInfoById) {
          return  $current=$jobInfoById->created_at;
        //$trialExpires []= $current->addDays(30);
     }
}
```

If i loop it it only show `1` data. How is it possible If use `array` sign then it will show `1` data.

Comment: What do you expect the `return` to do?

Comment: its because you of `return  $current=$jobInfoById->created_at;` this will  leave your loop after first iteration

Comment: The `return` leaves the `function`. I.e. it will only ever loop once.

Comment: foreach ($jobsInfoById as $jobInfoById){
          $var=  $current=$jobInfoById->created_at;
//            $trialExpires []= $current->addDays(30);
        } return $var;  //Same result I tried.

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to do or want to do. Are you getting Ids of jobs? Once you get the id why are you going thru the loop what is that you trying to do. I think the question is not clear enough sorry

Comment: What i am trying to do i want to get data based on category_id. Then i want to add 30 days on this created_at time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an array of all `created_at` dates, you don't need a loop.

```
public function showJobCategoryContent($id)
{

    $jobsInfoById = DB::table('jobs')->where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);

    return $jobsInfoById->pluck('created_at');
}
```

Using the loop:

```
public function showJobCategoryContent($id)
{

    $jobsInfoById = DB::table('jobs')->where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);

    $dates = [];
    foreach ($jobsInfoById as $jobInfoById) {
        $dates[] = $current = $jobInfoById->created_at;
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

If want to add 30 days to each date:

```
public function showJobCategoryContent($id)
{

    $jobsInfoById = DB::table('jobs')->where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);

    $jobsInfoById = $jobsInfoById->map(function ($job) {
        return $job->created_at->addDays(30);
    });

    return $jobsInfoById->pluck('created_at');
}
```

Have a look at Laravel collections and how they can be useful: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections)

Comment: To clarify, `pluck` uses a loop to internally iterate over the collection. So a loop is still being used, just somewhere else.

Comment: @fubar yes, thats right, but it much easier for you to look at and understand.

Comment: And `map` returns a new `Collection`, so you will need to assign the return value back to `$jobsInfoById`.

Comment: @Hamoud now the loop is working but if i use Add 30 days code then it show a error "Call to a member function addDays() on string"

Comment: Yes, because you're using `DB::table`, so it's not treated as a Model. If you have a Job model, change it to `Job::where('category_id')...`